# Do questions about specific issues belong here or on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm referring to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/35/is-this-possible-without-using-condition-variables) specifically.  The OP knows the code as-is doesn't work and is looking for the answer to a specific question.

Answer (score 19):

IMO fixing broken code should be off-topic here.

To be properly reviewed, code should at least pass basic tests, hopefully pass lint, pre-commit hooks and a full test run without known bugs or automated warnings (that'd be a waste of time for everyone involved).

Given the nature of the site, we are bound to meet "HELPMYCODEISBROKEN". I suggest we strictly move those to SO, but this is the easy part.

What happens with "this works, but is there a better way to..."? This could (I believe would) be on topic here, but if the line could be drawn at "coder is done picking options and ready to commit" we'd have an easier time figuring out whether to move stuff.

Comment: um, I assume by "OT" you mean off-topic and not on-topic?

Comment: The site to me is about Improving code, whilst sharing technique, and not fixing errors. +1

Comment: +1 I agree with what's been said here. If we start trying to figure out why someone else's piece of code doesn't work then it shifts the focus from improving the code to debugging the code which isn't what this SE is about. So I'd say such questions would fit better in SO.

Comment: +1 for the first sentence.  +many more if I could for the rest of the answer

Comment: created a discussion similar to this: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52/correcting-an-error-vs-reviewing-code please add your thoughts.